# When and why was $-1 \times -1$ defined to equal $1$?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, math-history

> When and why was $-1 \times -1$ defined to equal $1$?

My thoughts was that since the rational and natural numbers shared similar algebraic properties, maybe they wanted distributivity to hold for the negative numbers also. I have seen an algebraic derivation of the formula in question, but it relies on distributivity of negative multiplication.

Any thoughts or opinions appreciated. Thank you

Comment: See [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/historical-roots-of-the-justification-for-the-rule-for-multiplication-of-negativ)

Comment: Surely $-1 \times -1 \neq -1$, because multiplying a number by $-1$ should give you something different than what you started with. The only other plausible option is $-1 \times -1 = 1$. This seems nice because it extends to negative numbers the rule that multiplying by $-1$ flips the sign. It’s consistent with the idea that if I owe you a debt of 1 dollar then I will end up with 1 dollar once debts are settled. And it makes the axioms for the integers work. All roads lead to $-1 \times -1 =1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you explain Veites reasoning from the post you sent?

Comment: Consider $A-B$ positive and multiple it by $-G$ and compare it with $A$ times $-G$. If we assume + times - as negative, having $A$ positive, multipl it with $-G$ the result wiil be negative and greater in abs value to the product of $A-B$ times $-G$.

Comment: Thus, to equate the two results, we have to subtract from the bigger a quantity that must be positive, that is -B times -G.

Answer (score 7):

I really doubt that $-1 \cdot -1$ was *defined* to be $1$. However, you can *derive* that $-1 \cdot -1 = 1$ once you extend the Distributive property from natural numbers to all integers … though you also need to extend various other elementary properties regarding addition and multiplication from the natural numbers to the integers:

First, $-1$ is defined as that number such that, when you add $1$ to it, you get $0$.

So, if for now we refer to that number as $a$, we have

$$a+1=0$$

Multiplying both sides by $a$, we get:

$$a \cdot (a+1) = a \cdot 0$$

So if we extend the Distributive property:

$$(a \cdot a) + (a \cdot 1) = a \cdot 0$$

So, also extending the normal multiplicative properties involving $1$ and $0$:

$$(a \cdot a) + a = 0$$

Adding $1$ to each side

$$((a \cdot a) + a) + 1 = 0 + 1$$

So, using the Associative property:

$$(a \cdot a) + ( a+1) = 0+1$$

Since $a+1 =0$ and $0+1=1$, we get:

$$(a \cdot a) + 0 = 1$$

And so:

$$a \cdot a = 1$$

And there you have it:

$$-1 \cdot -1 =1$$

Comment: This is the derivation I referenced

Comment: @FraserPye Which *is* what you were looking for? Or not?

Comment: @FraserPye, do not mind. Definitively your answer is the best one here. For that reason I have already upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing a faster variant of [@Bram28's derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4833813):
in any [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition),
$$(-x)y=-(xy)$$ since
$$(-x)y+xy=(-x+x)y=0y=0.$$
Therefore (letting $x=1$ and $y=-1$)
$$(-1)^2=-(1\cdot(-1))=-(-1)=1.$$